# Setting anonymous type property name

Tags: c#, linq, properties, anonymous

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
string SomeConst = "OtherName";
var persons = GetPersons(); //returns list of Person
var q = persons.Select(p => 
new
{
    SomeConst = p.Name
});
```

Basically I'd expect to have in **q** sequence of anonymous type with the property
named **OtherName** and not **SomeConst**.
How can I achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: Why can't you just use `OtherName` in place of `SomeConst`?

Comment: That's the obvious solution and that's the way it's implemented now
I'm seeking for more generic solution now

Comment: if you've implemented it then what's the issue?

Comment: would const string SomeConst = "OtherName" do the trick?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't do that. The names of the properties of an anonymous type must be known at compile time. Why exactly do you need to do that?

You could achieve a similar effect by creating a sequence of dictionaries instead of anonymous objects:

```
string SomeConst = "OtherName";
var persons = GetPersons(); //returns list of Person
var q = persons.Select(p => 
new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { SomeConst, p.Name }
});
```

Comment: Say, the property name is to be extracted from a constant variable 
stored in some dictionary or even outside it. If the variable is constant isn't its value known at the compile time?

Comment: There's not such thing as a "constant variable"... If it's a constant, you can use the actual name directly when you create the anonymous object. If it's a variable, it's not possible, but you can do it with a dictionary as explained in my answer

Comment: So if I change the first line to
const string SomeConst

Comment: But WHY do you need to declare the property name as a constant?

Comment: Because I'm using this value elsewhere and wanted to avoid typing same string value in a thousand different places; therefore i just declared the variable to hold the value and one of the usages is as a property name in an anonymous type. apparently the framework doesn't allow for such a usage so I'll stick with other approach. Thanks for the patience

Comment: If you're using the same anonymous type in multiple places, you should create a named type

Comment: @MichaelG how? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of you can dynamically add properties whose name is unknown at compile time is the ExpandoObject :

```
var q = persons.Select(p => { dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject(); obj.Name = p.Name; return obj; });
```

But I really don't see any interest in doing such a thing. It is most probably a very bad design/idea to do so. You will undoubtly create more awkward, unreadable and unmaintenable code than you will solve anything...

Comment: this give me syntax error:"lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree"